# C# authenticate user under LDAP Domain

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, ldap

I was given this LDAP connection string:

> TestAD01/DC=example,DC=com

also LDAP domain:

> EXPLDOM

for me to able to authenticate user `test01` and password `pass123` using this snippet code:

```
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domainName, userName, password);
DirectorySearcher dsearch = new DirectorySearcher(de);
SearchResult results = null;

results = dsearch.FindOne();
```

what's the domainName i should put? because I already tried inputting `TestAD01/DC=example,DC=com` and `EXPLDOM` to domainName but i wasn't able to get the result

but when i try to put my computer's domain: `uat.example.com` on domainName, my application was successfully authenticating the given user credentials for my computer's domain

apologize for my confusing language

Answer (score 2):

An LDAP path consists of either:

1. The server to connect to, which can be the domain DNS name (`example.com`), or a specific DC (`dc1.example.com`), or
2. The distinguished name you want to bind to, like `DC=example,DC=com`)

or both.

If your computer is joined to the same domain that you're trying to connect to, or if your computer is joined to a trusted domain, then you don't need to include the server name. Your computer knows about the domain, so the distinguished name is enough for it to figure it out.

But if your computer is not joined to the same or trusted domain, then you must include the server name since your computer has no idea where to go for that domain.

It sounds like you will need to include the server name. If the distinguished name is `DC=example,DC=com` then the domain DNS name is `example.com`, and that's what you use as the server. (each "DC" part is a "domain component", which you can join together with dots in between)

That LDAP path would look something like this:

```
LDAP://example.com
```

You only need to include the distinguished name if you want to bind to something below the root of the domain. So this:

```
LDAP://example.com
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
LDAP://example.com/DC=example,DC=com
```

But if you wanted to search only one specific OU, then you *must* include the distinguished name of that OU:

```
LDAP://example.com/OU=Users,DC=example,DC=com
```